# No OnWebSocketConnect socket message

Tags: java, ssl, websocket, jetty

I am trying to connect to a test Web Socket ssl / wss server using the uri string "wss://domain:port" using Jetty (9.2.) and a self-signed certificate (truststore.jks) I created with keytool:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias certificatekey -keyalg RSA -validity 365 -keystore keystore.jks
keytool -export -alias certificatekey -keystore keystore.jks -rfc -file selfsignedcert.cer
keytool -import -alias certificatekey -file selfsignedcert.cer -keystore truststore.jks
```

and used the client code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  SslContextFactory ssl = new SslContextFactory();
  ssl.setKeyStoreResource(Resource.newResource("truststore.jks"));
  ssl.setKeyStorePassword(password);
  ssl.setKeyManagerPassword(password);
  WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient(ssl);
  MySocket socket = new MySocket();
  client.start();
  URI echoUri = new URI("wss://domain:port");
  ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();
  client.connect(socket, echoUri);
  socket.awaitClose(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  client.stop();
}
```

with my socket client code

```
@WebSocket
public class MySocket {
  ...
  @OnWebSocketConnect
  public void onConnect(Session session) {
    System.out.println("Got connect: "+session);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately there is no connect message ("Got connect...") from the socket method onConnect annotated with @OnWebSocket. It worked tho when using the unsecured server (ws instead of wss).

Comment: Show the output of `openssl s_client`.

Comment: Not sure how to show the output when the java code is running. However the ouput using "openssl s_client -connect URL:PORT" is this http://pastebin.com/StczwZq9

Comment: To test this I was using Kazing's Web Socket (echo.websocket.org:443) without wss:// in the beginning. When I added wss:// using openssl s_client in the beginnning I got a "getservbyname failure".

Comment: I generated another keystore via 

keytool -genkey -validity 3650 -keystore "keystore.jks" -storepass "password" -keypass "password" -alias "default" -dname "CN=127.0.0.1, OU=MyOrgUnit, O=MyOrg, L=MyCity, S=MyRegion, C=MyCountry"

and the following Java Class: http://pastebin.com/myvuyDJ9 It works on ws but not on wss. I also wiresharked the traffic. The client receives the certificate from the server and then the client cancels the connection I think (http://pastebin.com/A6XincaS). Any help would be highly appreciated. Toby

Comment: The issue here was that I needed first to download the server and then add this to my keystore (see http://pastebin.com/HdFuqpvu).

Comment: You should add your answer in a Answer block. Please don't use Pastebin in your answer, though. Its OK because that's how Stack Overflow works. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).